# Visual Studios 2012 Export Project Template with Files

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012

I can export a project to a template just fine, however, things are missing in the new project.

My goal is to create a template for code testing that requires some custom project/build/linking configurations. I found that I can preserve all these custom settings in an exported project. In addition to these settings is a directory that contains a .dll and .lib file. I have my paths set up as `$(ProjectDir)\supp\tester.dll`
-and-

```
$(ProjectDir)\supp\tester.lib
```

in their respective locations for linking.

The problem is that when I export the project as a template, and create a new project from the template, I am missing the tester.lib file in the supp directory. I even tried unzipping the template file and adding the tester.lib file back to SUPP, and rezipping it. I still cannot create a project from the template that includes the tester.lib file. Only the tester.dll file is created.

Do I have to set something up to tell VS to include this file in the template??

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a property sheet?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, although I am not sure if it was the most correct solution.

I had to export my project, unzip the resulting template, copying the tester.lib file to the unzipped file, and manually edit the templates .vstemplate file by adding:

```
<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="tester.lib">tester.lib</ProjectItem>
```

under the `<Project><\Project>` section. I then rezipped the files and put it in the Templates directory in the Visual Studios user area. Project I create with this template now include both the tester.dll and tester.lib files.