# How to add external dependencies to project template? (VS 2019)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I exported template from a project and when I create new project based on this template, external dependencies don't appear in it. Everything works, but IntelliSense says "cannot open source file".

Comment: For your reference: [Visual Studios 2012 Export Project Template with Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028748/visual-studios-2012-export-project-template-with-files).